# Show custom loading dialog with gif

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to get my application to display a simple loading dialog so users know when a time intensive process is working and when its done. I just want it to show a simple "loading" using a gif I downloaded. I already tried using only text and it still doesn't work.

I can get the dialog to display (and disappear) when I want it to, the problem is nothing will display on the dialog (or frame) after displaying it. I have tried many different techniques and all give the same result, a blank dialog.

I finally made a separate class to display the dialog (with loading gif) and I got it to display properly (by itself), but when I run it from my main application, it shows a black dialog again. I tested putting the gif into a JOptionPane and it works, the problem with that is I can't close it at will.

Here is my custom code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import java.util.logging.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class Loader implements Runnable  {

    final JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
    static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    Frame parentUI = new  Frame();
    JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
    JLabel lbl_filename = new JLabel();
    JLabel lbl_path = new JLabel();

    static Loader load = new Loader(null);


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, InvocationTargetException {
        load.run();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    } 

    public Loader(Frame parent) {
        init();
        parentUI = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        createDialog(parentUI);
    }  

    public final void init() {
        JButton btn = new JButton("Open");

        frame.setTitle("Loader Test");
        frame.setSize(500, 200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        btn.addActionListener(new Action1());

        frame.add(btn);
        frame.add(lbl_filename);
        frame.add(lbl_path);
    }

    class Action1 implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            openFile();
            load.Close();
        }
    }

    private void createDialog(final Frame parent) {

        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.setTitle("Loader");

        URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/resource/loader.gif");
        Icon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
        dialog.add(label);

        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(parent);
    }


    public void Show(Boolean visible) {
        this.run();
        dialog.setVisible(visible);
    }

    public void Close() {
        dialog.setVisible(false);
    }

    private void setJFCFilter(String file, String ext) {
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(file, ext);
        jfc.setFileFilter(filter);
    }

    private void openFile() {
        File default_dir = new File(".");
        jfc.setCurrentDirectory(default_dir);
        setJFCFilter("Scalable Vector Graphics", "svg");

        int returnVal = jfc.showOpenDialog(parentUI);

        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            String path = jfc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
            String fileName = jfc.getSelectedFile().getName();

            lbl_filename.setText(fileName);
            lbl_path.setText(path);

            load.Show(true);
            createDoc(path);
            load.Close();

        }
    }

    private void createDoc(String file) {
        try {
            NodeList svgIDPaths;

            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(file);

            String xpathIDExp = "//g/@id";

            XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath xpath = xpf.newXPath();
            XPathExpression expression = xpath.compile(xpathIDExp);

            svgIDPaths = (NodeList)expression.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Loader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Use this file for testing ->  [svg_test.svg](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6gremnwlxsz29b4/svg_test.svg?dl=0)

I have tried calling it like this:

```
loader.show(true);
```

And also in its own thread like this:

```
private void load(final Boolean visible) {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            loader.show(visible);
        }
    });

    t.start();
}
```

Neither method works and gives me the same result, a blank dialog. I have had this issue in the past, but just gave up and removed it (loading dialog). I have tried it with a progress bar and simple text, nothing seems to work.

Also I tried it in a JOptionPane and it worked, but that's not desirable (I want to close/open when I want not via a button click).

```
 private void load() {
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(MainForm.class.getResource("/resource/loader.gif").getFile());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Loading...", "Loader", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, icon);
    }
```

I am aware you can't run multiple dialogs on the EDT and have to use a separate thread, but I'm using a separate thread and its not working (it works by itself).

(Also note I have one main application (frame) that is running/opening this second dialog).

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: [mcve] or [sscce](http://sscce.org) please

Comment: Sorry, forgot. I'll update when I finish.

Comment: updated, open any SVG file and it will not work.

Comment: What do you mean by `// Java OutOfMemory`?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "ETF"? Are you referring to the Swing EDT -- the Event Dispatch Thread?

Comment: Ignore that comment, that was from a previous error. And yes I meant the EDT, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You look to have a Swing threading issue where you have long-running code on the event thread messing up drawing of images, and my guess is that the long running code is in your createDoc method. Consider calling that from a background thread, such as from a SwingWorker, and calling close on your load object only after the worker has completed its work. For example something like so:

```
class Action1 implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        openFile();
        // load.Close();  // get rid of this
    }
}

// .......

private void openFile() {

    // ....

    load.Show(true);  // load dialog on event thread

    new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            createDoc(path);  // call this from background thread
            return null;
        };

        protected void done() {
            load.Close();  // only call this once createDoc has completed
            // probably should call get() in here to catch all exceptions
        };
    }.execute();
}
```

Comment: You would be correct, the line that includes "expression.evaluate" load an SVG document into an object (possibly into memory as well) which takes a bit to load. Which is the reason for the loading dialog. I will try this and see if it works.

Comment: Another issue (a minor one), how can I use this with a modal dialog? My current dialog is non-modal allows users to click out of it and move it around. I want it to restrict any actions while its loading (to prevent any issues or problems). I tried setting it to modal when creating, but it just hangs up and does nothing. Any advice?

Comment: @LloydSmith: be sure to have everything correctly wired and running **before** setting the dialog visible. If still having problems, ask a new question, one with a valid [mcve], similar to the one above (although use a `Thread.sleep` for the long-running process).

Comment: What do you mean by "have everything correctly wired"?

Comment: All listeners added if any are need to be added. Understand that all code flow from the calling code stops after dialog has been set visible, and so all preparations need to be made before that happens.

Comment: Posted new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41289374/modal-dialog-not-working